# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED certificate verify failed - Google Colab

Tags: python, html, ssl, beautifulsoup, google-colaboratory

I am trying to **scrape** data from a url using beautifulsoup. Below is my code

```
import requests

URL = "https://bigdataldn.com/speakers/"
page = requests.get(URL)

print(page.text)
```

However I am getting the following error when I run the code in google colab.

```
SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='bigdataldn.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)')))
```

[image: Screenshot of Error]

The above code works fine for other urls.
Can someone help me figure out how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not your fault - their certificate chain is not properly configured. What you can do is disabling the certificate verification (you should not do this when you're handling sensitive information!) but it might be fine for a webscraper.

```
page = requests.get(URL, verify=False)
```

Comment: DO NOT USE `verify=False` ! unless you know what you are doing, especially if you care about your security

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Yes, I indicated that in my answer though. Do you see any other way if the chain of trust is misconfigured?

Comment: the only way is to manually verify the cert by downloading the current or previous cert.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YU7iK.png)

Your SSL certificate is not installed properly , you can follow godaddy ssl install instruction maybe its helpfull .
https://in.godaddy.com/help/install-my-ssl-certificate-16623?sp_hp=B&xpmst=A&xpcarveout=B